# Building grid for "candy crush - like" game in libGDX

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, swap

I'm starting creting prototype for android, candy crush - like game, using libGDX. Thats the first time I'm working with this game library, so I would be thankful if someone would point me to efficient way to create grid. Currentlu I'm doing it like this: I have 2d array Ball[][] and 2d array Vector2[][]. In grid constructor I calculate coords of every slot, and than,when I'm populating grid, I obatain Ball from pool and assign apropiet grid coords (Vector2[row][column], Ball[row][column]). Each ball remembers own row and column, and when I swap candy, when MoveToAction is finished i swap balls in array and assign to them new coords from new location. 
  But I'm now sure if thats the best idea. I was thinking about creating one 2d array with value pairs Pair and during swap reassign ball to their new pair. It seems cleaner, but since grid it incredibly important part of game, I would like to know with way is best? How other people are solving swapping problem? What are pros and cons of both solutions?

Comment: You shouldn't assume that people know what Candy Crush is, i.e. give a brief explanation of it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I should be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you aren't being generous enough with data structures. You have the Ball object which holds every property unique to the Ball objects themselves and then you have an array that holds those balls which is great. But then you have the array that holds the positions for each ball and that's your problem.

If you think about the way youre doing it the ball array holds the ball at the specified row and column, and then in the grid array you hold the positions that the ball should be set to. This is very confusing and can be done easier with more use of objects.

Assume that we create a class GridSlot that represents one slot on the grid. We can drop the Ball and Vector2 arrays and forget about them. Instead we will create an array of type GridSlot[] that will hold each slot in the array (keep in mind that it's a one-dimensional array). In the GridSlot class we can create two variables, x and y, that represent the position of the slot and we can create another variable, ball, that represents the Ball in the slot. Now when initializing everything, when you normally load the vector2 array with positions, we can instead create a new GridSlot object and set the correct position to that object instead. We will do this for each slot in the grid and then when we want to move a ball to a slot all you have to do is set the ball variable within the GridSlot object.

Comment: It seems great idea and I will implement it. But I see one problem. Without 2dimensional array i don't know row and column of each grid slot so it's impossible to determine ball to swap with. Example: click on ball and drag finger left, ball from grid slot row,column, must swap places with ball from raw, colum-1. So i think array GridSlot[][] work better?

Comment: Yeah that's not a problem either! 2d or 1d array will work, just make sure the positions are generated correctly.

Comment: I will. I'm currently implementing this. Didn't finished jet, but it looks nice and simple. Thanks a million man!